# How to split string like ladder in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a string `str:str2:str3` and I want get array of strings with next elements `['str', 'str:str2', 'str:str2:str3']`.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `split().join()` can be used.

Comment: what approaches did you try ?

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm looking for the best solution, but I don't know how to solve this task with only `split` and `join`. I was thinking that may be `split` by regex can help solve this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string by `':'` and build a new array with the wanted parts.

```js
var SEPARATOR = ':',
    string = 'str:str2:str3',
    temp = string.split(SEPARATOR),
    result = temp.map(function (a, i, aa) {
        return aa.slice(0, i + 1).join(SEPARATOR);
    });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string and generate the element by slicing splitted array based on the index.

```js
console.log(
  'str:str2:str3'
  .split(':')
  .reduce(function(arr, v, i, spl) {
    arr.push(spl.slice(0, i + 1).join(':'));
    return arr;
  }, [])
);
```